# Android: getting columns from another parseObject being pointed at

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have two ParseObjects: Trip and Schedule. Trip has an "assignedSchedule" column which points to a Schedule ParseObject. I get all rows of Trip and display them as a listview:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> trip = ParseQuery.getQuery("Trip");
trip.include("assignedSchedule");
trip.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
     ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.schedule);
     SampleCustomAdapter adapter = new SampleCustomAdapter(list);
     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

So, my custom adapter takes in an arrayList of Trip and display them as views. I need the "day" and "time" which are columns of Schedule. How do I get them?
I keep finding:

```
   var day = result[i].get("assignedSchedule").get("day");
```

or something similar as the solution but this is for javascript. It doesn't seem to work on android. I do this:

```
ParseObject schedule = list.get(index);
schedule.get("assignedSchedule").get("day");
```

By the second .get, it says that it cannot resolve the method. I tried turning it into an array instead of an arrayList, tried to instantiate it as an Object instead of a ParseObject but it still gets the same error

Any suggestions would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Schedule object as :

```
ParseObject schedule = (Schedule)(list.get(position).getParseObject("assignedSchedule"));
```